# Free Fast Image Processing Library for C# that can Handle Large Images Quickly

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics

Im trying to adjust the contrast,brightness etc of a large images of resolutions 3000X2000 and higher.GDI+ is too slow to this.So im looking for free 3rd party libraries.I have tried **Aforge.Net** but its no different.There is **Emgu** which is a port of **openCV** but it does not allow free commercial use.Image magik is also an option.But there is no documentation of any sort for C#.Is there any other free alternatives?